# Popup from within email

Tags: workflow, email, outlook, popup

Ok, I have a client with a peculiar request. He wants to receive an (generated by a workflow) email with a hyperlink that will open a pop-up dialog if you click on it. Note: the link within the email should open a popup and not a web page in a browser.

I immediately thought this would be impossible, but after looking around a bit I found out that you can create a workflow variable with tags in them and insert them into the email body.

eg: `<a href="some_page.asp">here</a>`

The conclusion that I draw from this is that an email consists of html code that the email client renders. Now I'm wondering if there is a way to make use of a tag no cause a modal dialog to pop up?

I guess the question is what functionality the email client (Microsoft Outlook) supports. I can't figure how to attach some JavaScript or something that will be used by Outlook. Is there perhaps some embedded functionality within Outlook to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

This is email client dependent. As some email clients are purely web-based this would be possible (gmail.com, outlook.com etc.) but many software email clients completely disallow javascript within email body context as javascript is a potential security threat.

MS Office Outlook does not support javascript. As mentioned, javascript within email body context is a security threat and disallowed.

The best you can do is have a link which open a webpage where this popup shows.